# jquery.ui.selectmenu redirects to index page instead of submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, opera

I use `jquery.ui.selectmenu.js` plugin for custom selects on my website.
My select has binded onchenge event which does `$(this).closest('form').submit();`
The problem is that in **Opera** it does not submit the form - it redirects to index page and adds `#nogo` to url.
I find the reason in plugin.
There are such pieces of code there:

```
    this.newelement = $( '<a />', {
        'class': this.widgetBaseClass + ' ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all',
        'id' : this.ids[ 1 ],
        'role': 'button',
        'href': '#nogo',
        'tabindex': this.element.attr( 'disabled' ) ? 1 : 0,
        'aria-haspopup': true,
        'aria-owns': this.ids[ 2 ]
    });
```

The question is - what should I replace `#nogo` with to fix it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `javascript:void(0);`